# Fastest access of intensive function from PHP?

Tags: c#, php, c++, c, performance

**Background**:
I have a PHP server hosting a RESTful API that returns an image when a function */api/GenerateImage* is called. I need the fastest and lowest memory using method to achieve this.

**Ideas**:
  I can think of a few ways of achieving this:

1. Write it entirely in PHP - Image requires a lot of byte manipulation and it feels bad to do this in PHP.
2. Write a continually running C# program and use an API to generate the image and copy the response stream to the client via PHP - Need to avoid overhead of unnecessary socket connections.
3. Write a C/C++ command line program that, when called, generates and stores the image in a file, which PHP reads and sends - Need to avoid overhead due to starting a program, writing to a file and then reading to it.
4. Write it in C/C++ and use a PHP library wrapper to call the function directly from PHP - Seems to be the fastest, but most difficult for a single function.

Comment: Dear user who voted to close, care to explain why? The question meets all the suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and is clear and has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most obvious solutions to me seem absent from your set of options:

- Use PHP's GD extension.
- Use imagemagick.

Whether these are practical options depends on what exactly you have to do with the image.  If they are just static images you don't need anything, just serve them up as files from your web server.  The fact you need some code to generate the image implies that the image is dynamically generated.

If neither of these suit, then I would say: your last (4th) solution would be the fastest, but a modified version of your 3rd solution would be simplest: write a command-line program that returns the image data to stdout, and call that from PHP.